# Windows 10 Black Screen after killing Explorer.exe

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

I want to run an application without explorer.exe running in Windows10.

But when I kill the Explorer.exe I get a black screen. Is there any way to have a background image instead of that black screen.

I know that maybe there is other options instead of killing the explorer.exe, but I do not want to do any other options.

It should be very simple to change that black screen to something nice, but I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Windows 7 didn't do that. We were able to set a background while explorer was kiiled.

Comment: File Explorer has been significantly improved since it was Windows Explorer (Windows 7 and earlier).  In this case while it might have been possible on Windows 7 it is no longer possible on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to have a window with the background image,
creating it over the entire screen and setting it to topmost.
The real window can be a child of it, so it is positioned before it.

Note that this same solution will also work without killing Explorer,
but this is your choice.

Comment: Yes this option is a very valid option, and would work for sure. But with previous version of windows we didn't have to do that. We could set a wall paper and it would stay when you kill the explorer.exe. So I was trying to achieve the same thing without having to make any changes to the app.

Comment: I'm not aware of a Windows version that behaved like that since many years.

Comment: Windows 7 does, that's why we would expect this to continue working with w10